# Installation issue in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, apache2, redmine

I have installed Redmine in my Ubuntu server. After installation when I access

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

it's loading but Redmine doesn't open. How do I configure Apache2? In ports.conf file I have changed "listen 80" to "listen 3000" and saved it. If I restart Apache2 using sudo service apache2 restart I am getting the following error:

> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:3000
>   (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:3000
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   AH00015: Unable to open logs
>   Action 'start' failed.
>   The Apache error log may have more information.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Redmine in standalone?

Stop apache / Relaunch Redmine And try to connect on `http://localhost:3000`

Generally Apache is used as a proxy to redmine with the proxy_pass and passenger modules.